# Rpmfusion nvidia driver is not loaded (Kernel 4.14.11-300)

Tags: fedora, gnome, nvidia

I have installed rpmfusion nvidia drivers on my FC27/gnome. However after reboot system says "Nvidia kernel modules is not loaded fallback to nouveau"

```
[root@dmitry]/home/dmitry# uname -a                            
Linux dmitry.semenov 4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 3 13:52:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@dmitry]/home/dmitry# dnf list installed | grep nvidia
akmod-nvidia.x86_64                    2:387.34-1.fc27                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
kmod-nvidia-4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64.x86_64
nvidia-settings.x86_64                 387.34-1.fc27                   @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia.x86_64             2:387.34-2.fc27                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc.x86_64     2:387.34-2.fc27                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.x86_64        2:387.34-2.fc27                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates

[root@dmitry]/home/dmitry# lspci |grep -E "VGA|3D" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)

[root@dmitry]/home/dmitry# ls /lib/modules/4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64/extra/nvidia  
nvidia-drm.ko  nvidia.ko  nvidia-modeset.ko  nvidia-uvm.ko
```

as far as I can see Nvidia 940MX is [supported](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/387.34/README/supportedchips.html)

#### am I missing something?

Comment: `akmod` and `kmod` driver packages from rpmfusion have given me plenty of headaches on nvidia systems in the past (either lagging behind or failed module builds). I have now switched my Nvidia systems to other OSes (gentoo and SolusOS) to be rid of this headache.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure `nouveau` is not loaded:

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

If it is, switch to the text console (`ctrl+alt+f3`), login as root, activate runlevel 3:

```
systemctl isolate runlevel3.target
```

Remove the `nouveau` module:

```
rmmod nouveau
```

Try loading the `nvidia` module manually:

```
modprobe nvidia
```

Start the X:

```
startx
```

Note that NVIDIA + Gnome + Wayland need some tweaking, it's described in the RPM Fusion's [Howto/NVIDIA](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA) in section Wayland. (There is also a section about nouveau, it may help you find out why your nouveau module was not blacklisted).

If this helps you, the nouveau module is not blacklisted although I thought the drivers from RPM Fusion did that automatically. Go to `/etc/modprobe.d/` and try finding a `.conf` file that could be blacklisting `nouveau`:

```
grep nouveau /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf
```

If there's no such file, create one, let's say `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` with just one line

```
blacklist nouveau
```

Now you need to rebuild the init ramdrive against your current kernel using dracut:

```
dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```